# NullPointerException when inserting object into Drools AbstractWorkingMemory

Tags: grails, drools

I have a Grails app that I'm in the process of upgrading from v 1.3.7 to 2.3.4. We have some Drools related functionality that was working in 1.3.7 but does not work with 2.3.4. I'm not quite sure what the issue is, because the Drools dependencies have not changed and I cannot make much sense of the error that I'm getting, so I was hoping that someone could perhaps shed some light on what could possibly cause this error.

Here's a snippet of the code where it's blowing up:

```
 def session = ruleBase.newStatefulSession()

 // put objects in session
 objList.each {obj ->
     session.insert(obj)
 }
```

Contents of objList is a single composite object of this type:

```
public class ConsumerPrequalificationComposite extends PrequalificationComposite {
InsuranceApplicationPerson insAppPerson
List<Person> applicants

public boolean isDisabled(String questionKey, String answer) {
    return getAnswerToQuestion(questionKey).equals(answer);
}

String getAnswerToQuestion(String questionTypeOrUserDefinedKey) {
    if (!person) {
        return null
    }

    def answerList = person.answers ? person.answers : insAppPerson.answers

    if (answerList) {
        return getAnswerToQuestion(answerList, questionTypeOrUserDefinedKey)
    } else {
        return null
    }
}

@Override
boolean benefitIncludesIndividualYoungerThanOnRequestedEffectiveDate(int years, int months, int days) {
    if (super.benefitIncludesIndividualYoungerThanOnRequestedEffectiveDate(years, months, days)) {
        return true
    }

    for (Person applicant in applicants) {
        if (onDateWillBeYoungerThan(applicant, this.requestedEffectiveDate, years, months, days)) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

boolean isSingleApplicant() {
    return applicants?.size() == 1
}
}

abstract class PrequalificationComposite extends DroolsComposite {
List planRuleHandles = []
Map<InsuranceType, Date> requestedEffectiveDates = [:]
Map insTypeFailureReasons = [:]
List selectedInsuranceTypes = []
String agentId
boolean validLocation
List<PaymentDurationType> paymentDurationTypes = []

// Added these because grails adds a get for booleans and drools looks for a is
boolean isValidLocation() {
    return this.validLocation
}

boolean getValidLocation() {
    return this.validLocation
}

void setValidLocation(boolean isValid) {
    this.validLocation = isValid
}

void addPlan(String ruleHandle){
    planRuleHandles << ruleHandle
}

void addPaymentDurationType(PaymentDurationType paymentDurationType) {
    paymentDurationTypes.add(paymentDurationType)
}

void addFailureReason(InsuranceType insType, ContentKey contentKey) {
    insTypeFailureReasons.put(insType, contentKey)
}

boolean hasFailureReason(InsuranceType insuranceType) {
    return insTypeFailureReasons.get(insuranceType) != null
}

String getAnswerToQuestion(String questionTypeOrUserDefinedKey){
    if(!person){
        return null
    }

    return getAnswerToQuestion(person.answers, questionTypeOrUserDefinedKey)

}

Date getAnswerToQuestionAsDate(String questionTypeOrUserDefinedKey){
    def answer = getAnswerToQuestion(questionTypeOrUserDefinedKey)
    if (answer) {
        Date dateAvailable = DateUtil.parse(answer)
        return dateAvailable
    }

    return null
}

boolean olderThanOnJanOneOfRequestedEffectiveDateForInsuranceType(InsuranceType insType, int years, int months, int days) {
    def requestedEffectiveDate = requestedEffectiveDates[insType] ?: new Date()
    def cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.setTime(requestedEffectiveDate)
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0)
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1)
    def janOne = cal.getTime()
    onDateWillBeOlderThan(janOne, years, months, days)  // have to add 1 to the year becuase needs to be "older than"
}

boolean youngerThanOnRequestedEffective(int years, int months, int days) {
    onDateWillBeYoungerThan(this.requestedEffectiveDate, years, months, days)
}

boolean olderThanOnRequestedEffective(int years, int months, int days) {
    onDateWillBeOlderThan(this.requestedEffectiveDate, years, months, days)
}

boolean olderThanOnRequestedEffectiveForInsuranceType(InsuranceType insType, int years, int months, int days) {
    onDateWillBeOlderThan(getEffectiveDate(insType), years, months, days)
}

boolean heightWeightAgeValid(int minYears, int minMonths, int maxYears, int maxMonths, int minHeight, int maxHeight, int minWeight, int maxWeight) {
    def result = false
    if (olderThanNow(minYears, minMonths, 0) && !olderThanNow(maxYears, maxMonths, 0)) {
        if (person.height > minHeight && person.height < maxHeight && person.weight > minWeight && person.weight < maxWeight) {
            result = true
        }
    }
    return result
}

public void setState(String state) {
    person.address.state = state
}

boolean checkEffectiveDates(InsuranceType insType, String dateAvailableString) {
    def requestedEffectiveDate = this.requestedEffectiveDates[insType] ?: new Date()
    def dateAvailable = DateUtil.parse(dateAvailableString)
    return (dateAvailable.equals(requestedEffectiveDate) || dateAvailable.before(requestedEffectiveDate)) 
}

public abstract boolean isDisabled( String questionKey, String answer );

boolean hasSelectedInsuranceType(InsuranceType insType) {
    return selectedInsuranceTypes.any { it == insType }
}

String getAgentId() {
    return agentId
}

Date getEffectiveDate(InsuranceType insType) {
    Date requestedEffectiveDate = this.requestedEffectiveDates[insType] ?: new Date()
    return requestedEffectiveDate
}

/**
 * Checks all individuals to be covered on the benefit and returns true if any of them are/will be younger than the
 * specified age as of the requested effective date
 */
boolean benefitIncludesIndividualYoungerThanOnRequestedEffectiveDate(int years, int months, int days) {
    if (person && onDateWillBeYoungerThan(person, this.requestedEffectiveDate, years, months, days)) {
        return true
    }

    for (InsuranceApplicationPlanPerson planPerson in insuranceApplicationPlan?.insuranceApplicationPlanPersons) {
        if (onDateWillBeYoungerThan(planPerson.insuranceApplicationPerson.person, this.requestedEffectiveDate, years, months, days)) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

boolean isFfm() {
    return person.ffmEligibilityInfo != null
}

boolean isQhpEligibility() {
    return person.ffmEligibilityInfo ? person.ffmEligibilityInfo.qhpEligibilityIndicator : false
}

boolean isCsrEligibility() {
    return person.ffmEligibilityInfo ? person.ffmEligibilityInfo.csrEligibilityIndicator : false
}

}

abstract class DroolsComposite {

InsuranceApplicationPlan insuranceApplicationPlan
Person person
Date requestedEffectiveDate

String getAnswerToQuestion(Collection<Answer> answers, String questionTypeOrUserDefinedKey) {

    def answerString = null
    def answer = null
    try{
        def questionType = QuestionType.valueOf(QuestionType.class, questionTypeOrUserDefinedKey)
        answer = answers.find {
            it.question.questionType == questionType
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        Logger.getLogger(this.class).debug("QuestionType could not be determined for $questionTypeOrUserDefinedKey this is not an error.  The value could be referencing a question user defined key value")
    }

    if (!answer){
        answer = answers.find {
            if (it.question == null) {
                println "OH MY GOLLY!"
            }
            it.question.userDefinedKey.equals(questionTypeOrUserDefinedKey)
        }
    }

    if (answer) {
        if (answer.question.multiListAnswerType == PossibleAnswerType.USER_CONFIGURED) {
            def possibleAnswer = answer.question.possibleAnswers.find {
                it.id.toString().equals(answer.stringValue) 
            }
            answerString = possibleAnswer.userDefinedKey
        } else {
            answerString = answer.toString()
        }
    }
    return answerString

}

boolean olderThanNow(int years, int months, int days) {
    onDateWillBeOlderThan(new Date(), years, months, days)
}

boolean onDateWillBeOlderThan(Date date, int years, int months, int days) {
    def result = false
    def target = Calendar.getInstance()
    target.setTime(date)
    target.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1)
    def ageCal = Calendar.getInstance()
    ageCal.setTime(person.dateOfBirth)
    ageCal.add(Calendar.YEAR, years)
    ageCal.add(Calendar.MONTH, months)
    ageCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, days)

    if (ageCal.before(target)) {
        result = true
    }

    return result
}

boolean youngerThanNow(int years, int months, int days) {
    onDateWillBeYoungerThan(new Date(), years, months, days)
}

boolean onDateWillBeYoungerThan(Date date, int years, int months, int days) {
    def result = false
    def target = Calendar.getInstance()
    target.setTime(date)
    def ageCal = Calendar.getInstance()
    ageCal.setTime(person.dateOfBirth)
    ageCal.add(Calendar.YEAR, years)
    ageCal.add(Calendar.MONTH, months)
    ageCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, days)

    if (ageCal.after(target)) {
        result = true
    }

    return result
}

boolean onDateWillBeYoungerThan(Person personToCheck, Date date, int years, int months, int days) {
    Calendar targetDate = Calendar.getInstance()
    targetDate.setTime(date)

    Calendar dateAgeReached = Calendar.getInstance()
    dateAgeReached.setTime(personToCheck.dateOfBirth)
    dateAgeReached.add(Calendar.YEAR, years)
    dateAgeReached.add(Calendar.MONTH, months)
    dateAgeReached.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,days)

    return dateAgeReached.after(targetDate)
}

boolean olderThanOnJanOneOfRequestedEffective(int years, int months, int days) {
    def cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.setTime(this.requestedEffectiveDate)
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0)
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1)
    def janOne = cal.getTime()
    onDateWillBeOlderThan(janOne, years, months, days)  // have to add 1 to the year becuase needs to be "older than"
}

boolean getDisability() {
    return insuranceApplicationPlan != null ? insuranceApplicationPlan.policyOwner?.insuranceApplicationPerson?.disability : null
}

Relationship getRelationshipToOwner() {
    return person.relationshipToOwner
}

Date getRequestedEffectiveDate() {
    return requestedEffectiveDate
}

public InsuranceApplicationPlan getInsuranceApplicationPlan() {
    return insuranceApplicationPlan
}

public Date getDateOfBirth() {
    return person.dateOfBirth
}

public String getCsrLevel() {
    return person?.ffmEligibilityInfo?.csrLevel ?: null
}

public Integer getRequestedEffectiveDateYear() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    if (getRequestedEffectiveDate() != null) {
        return 0
    }
    cal.setTime(insuranceApplicationPlan.getEffectiveDateOrRequestedIfNull())
    return cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
}

}
```

ruleBase is a ReteooRuleBase and session is an AbstractWorkingMemory. The exception that I get occurs on the insert call and it is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.drools.core.rule.PredicateConstraint.isAllowed(PredicateConstraint.java:299)
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.AlphaNode.assertObject(AlphaNode.java:134)
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.doPropagateAssertObject(CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.java:502)
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.propagateAssertObject(CompositeObjectSinkAdapter.java:387)
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.ObjectTypeNode.assertObject(ObjectTypeNode.java:288)
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.EntryPointNode.assertObject(EntryPointNode.java:260)
    at org.drools.core.common.NamedEntryPoint.insert(NamedEntryPoint.java:360)
    at org.drools.core.common.NamedEntryPoint.insert(NamedEntryPoint.java:279)
    at org.drools.core.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.insert(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:1149)
    at org.drools.core.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.insert(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:1093)
```

It does seem to work when inserting other objects into session, but there is nothing really special about this specific object that I'm trying to insert other than that it extends another abstract class that in turn extends another abstract class. However, all of this works in Grails 1.3.7. I've tried debugging the Drools source, but I'm not really getting any good leads there either.

I am using Drools 6.0.0.Final

Comment: What is inside objList? You must provide details about that as it is the source of the problem.

Comment: I added the class as well as the class it extends to the description.

Comment: I don't see strange stuff here... Maybe it is about your rules then. Inserting other facts don't generate this exception, so do you know which rules are fired with your special object? Maybe there is some eval(...) in it that creates the null pointer at runtime because a field of your object is null and the rules tries to get a field on it.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, you're right. I stripped down the rules file to a super basic one and then it does work, so it definitely has to be related to that. It's weird that this exact same file works just by using an older version of Grails though. I guess something must be winding up on the classpath that is throwing off things. I'll try slowly adding rules back to the rules file and see if I can isolate which rule in particular it is that is causing things to blow up.

Comment: @zenbeni Thanks so much! I was able to track down the rule that caused the issue and I should be able to have it resolved shortly.